# If parity is set to be 1 then how to check for error bit in hamming code without knowing the if the parity is even or odd?

Tags: hamming-code

A seven-bit Hamming code is received as 1110101. What is the correct code? Assume the parity to be one.

The problem I am facing here is I don't know how to check parity without knowing it is even or odd.

Comment: Use the decoding procedure shown in class.

Comment: which class you are talking about?

Comment: There is a decoding algorithm for Hamming codes. It is explained on Wikipedia and in other sources. Applying the algorithm requires no creativity – a computer can (literally) do it automatically.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#.5B7.2C4.5D_Hamming_code_with_an_additional_parity_bit